# Editing bash script in vim, <<< brackets cause colour corruption

Tags: bash, vim, vi

I have inherited several bash scripts that uses the following syntax to read from a string into an array:

```
read -a arr <<<$line
```

However, this causes the colour formatting in vim to break. Can anybody suggest a quick fix?

Update:

Ignore the content of the script, but note the colour variation after the '<<<' characters (i.e. echo statements are in purple):

[image]

Comment: What version of vim? What version of the runtime highlighting files? How does it "break"?

Comment: Hi Etan, its vim 7.3 running on a mac but to be honest, i've seen the issue on many version of vim. Just wondered if anybody else had encountered it.

Comment: It looks like it's interpreting `<<<` as introducing a heredoc with the terminator `<`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It happens if the `#!/bin/bash` shebang line is missing. Vim interprets the script as plain sh instead of bash. `<<<` is a bash-ism.

From `sh.syntax`:

```
" trying to answer the question: which shell is /bin/sh, really?
" If the user has not specified any of g:is_kornshell, g:is_bash, g:is_posix, g:is_sh, then guess.
if !exists("g:is_kornshell") && !exists("g:is_bash") && !exists("g:is_posix") && !exists("g:is_sh")
 let s:shell = ""
 if executable("/bin/sh")
  let s:shell = resolve("/bin/sh")
 elseif executable("/usr/bin/sh")
  let s:shell = resolve("/usr/bin/sh")
 endif
 if     s:shell =~ 'bash$'
  let g:is_bash= 1
 elseif s:shell =~ 'ksh$'
  let g:is_kornshell = 1
 elseif s:shell =~ 'dash$'
  let g:is_posix = 1
 endif
 unlet s:shell
endif
```

and

```
" Here Strings: {{{1
" =============
" available for: bash; ksh (really should be ksh93 only) but not if its a posix
if exists("b:is_bash") || (exists("b:is_kornshell") && !exists("g:is_posix"))
 syn match shRedir "<<<"        skipwhite       nextgroup=shCmdParenRegion
endif
```

Comment: In my case it was because I was using #/usr/bin/env sh - changed to bash - thank you

Comment: @SteveWalsh Setting the buffer variable `is_bash` is better than changing your shebang line most likely.

Comment: @EtanReisner: nope, keeping `sh` on the shebang line may cause the script to fail in horrible ways on machines where `sh` is not `bash`.

Comment: @ninjalj From `/usr/bin/env sh` to `/usr/bin/env bash`, yes. But I don't know that vim will trigger on that either (though perhaps it does). I was mostly suggesting that moving to `/bin/bash` isn't the right answer.

Comment: @EtanReisner `/usr/bin/env bash` is okay too; vim looks for `bash` or `bash2` (with word boundaries on either side) on the first line of the file to identify a shell script as bash.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like vim has support for the `<<<` construct in the sh syntax file, but it only recognizes it if it believes the file is a bash script. Some ways to make vim think that the file is bash:

1. Give it a shebang of `#!/bin/bash`, not just `#!/bin/sh` (this is best practice if the file uses bash-specific constructs anyway)
2. Have `/bin/sh` on the system where you're editing be a symlink to `bash` (meh)
3. Add `let g:is_bash = 1` to your `.vimrc` to make vim assume that shell scripts are bash by default.

Answer (score 1):

To make it easier for others to know what's the problem I did a quick test on `OS X Yosemite 10.10.5` with `vim 7.4.640` and here are the screenshots:

[image]

[image]

And as other answers pointed out, using `#!/bin/bash` as the shebang line fixes the problem for me.